# Rails DB Migration - permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails novice, but am currently trying to modify an existing application that I inherited.

I'm running some db migrations that create new tables on our staging server (Not local machine) and all the new DB tables create seem to have different permissions than the tables already created.

I am running "rake db:migrate VERSION=20110213100531 RAILS_ENV=staging" with one sshlogin and I have my sql login defined in my database.yml under staging as separate mysql database login.

Is there any particular settings/user I should be running my db migration under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said I think most likely your problems are being caused from the way you have your user permissions set up in the remote database. This is not something that can be altered from the rails side.

Your database.yml file will just specify your login details into that database, but it's up to you to modify your user permissions settings in your database.

If you've got admin access into your database, I'd start by comparing the previous user's permissions to your own and seeing what's the difference.

All the best

Comment: Thanks for the help - the problem was actually a problem with PHPMyAdmin and extra database migrations that were accidentally run.